# How to seed data into Mongo database with mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, seeding

I realize this should probably be pretty straightforward but I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I am building a schema with mongoose, and I want the schema to have some default values when the program runs. Is this possible to do in the mongoose schema, or do I have to have another file that seeds the database when the program runs? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Tried to just set default values in mongoose, but it didn't work. The datatype is a string. It's just a schema with one item: A name. I want the database to be seeded with multiple instances of the schema created automatically.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but [`mgodatagen`](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen "Link to GitHub project page -->") is really usefully for staging example/practice MongoDB databases.  Oversimplifying a bit, you create a schema and `mgodatagen` will create and insert as many documents (and indexes) as you want.  You could use `mgodatagen`'s `faker` method to create a bunch of names.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question right, but have you checked [Declaring Defaults in Your Schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html)?